# FromRoute does not set Url parameters in separate DTO class

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

When creating a new Web API project you might come up with controller endpoints expecting url params, body values and maybe queries, especially for PATCH routes.

So let's assume you would like to update your shop basket by changing the amount of a product. The endpoint expects the order id and product id from the url and the amount from the body.

```
[HttpPatch("{orderId}/products/{productId}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Update(Dto dto)
{
    return Ok(dto);
}
```

The matching `Dto` should hold the values from the whole request

```
public class Dto
{
    [FromRoute]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }

    [FromRoute]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    [FromBody]
    public int Amount { get; set; }
}
```

When calling the API via PATCH https://localhost:5001/orders/123/products/456 `Amount` is correct but both ID parameters are 0. I think they won't be set and will have their default value.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is a web api project, the [ApiController] attribute applies inference rules for the default data sources of action parameters. The Dto is a complex type, so it will use [FromBody] as default.

When [FromBody] is applied to a complex type parameter, any binding source attributes applied to its properties are ignored. This is why you can't get the OrderId and ProductId, the [FromRoute] attribute on them are ignored.

You can find it from the official documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#binding-source-parameter-inference

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1#frombody-attribute

One solution is that you can receive them separately:

```
[HttpPatch("{orderId}/products/{productId}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Update(Dto dto, int orderid, int productId)
{
    return Ok(dto);
}
```

Comment: so there is no way to merge them together? Because I could directly map the whole DTO to another Object using AutoMapper and your solution provided above would break this :/

Comment: Seems can't, but you can fill id to dto in the action.

Comment: hm the problem is that `[FromQuery]` comes up with even more problems. So DTOs only work for the body? Are there any solutions to have e.g. 3 DTOs (ids, body, queries) and merge them together later on? This looks a little bit messy

Comment: like so https://hatebin.com/mqqhnkqrod when calling the url PATCH https://localhost:5001/foo/123/456?doit=true

Comment: yeah, If you indicate the source before the parameter, he will look up the data from the corresponding source.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. This helped me.

In the controller, you need to specify [FromRoute]:

```
[HttpPatch("{orderId}/products/{productId}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Update([FromRoute] Dto dto)
{
    return Ok(dto);
}
```

In the DTO, on the fields that should be obtained from the body, you need to specify [FromBody]:

```
public class Dto
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }

    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    [FromBody]
    public int Amount { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: this is not correct and does not work